# Camera of android becomes null when switching from third activity to second or 1st Activity

Tags: android, android-camera

Why Surface View camera becomes null after switching from one activity to another in Android? When there were 2 classes and I was switching from 1st to 2nd Activity and from 2nd to 1st Activity, everything was working fine. But when I started a new activity, that is the third one, switching from third to any other activity makes camera null that's why the activity crashes but when clicked on "OK" the application continues. (In my code, Camera1 becomes null). What could be the reason of it? I don't want the message to appear that the activity has crashed

train.class(3rd Activity)

```
public void saveClicked(View v) {

    save.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    saveName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    txtEditor.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    try {

        //label++;

        File Root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        LabelFile = new File(Root, "labels.txt");
        roughFile= new File(Root,"rough.txt");
        FileWriter Writter = new FileWriter(roughFile,false);
        out = new BufferedWriter(Writter);

        if(!roughFile.exists()){
            roughFile.createNewFile();
            Writter.write("a," +number);
        }

        ///*-*---------------------------------------------------------------*-*//
         aFile = new File(Root, "string.txt");
         FileWriter aWritter = new FileWriter(aFile,true);
         BufferedWriter bWritter = new BufferedWriter(aWritter);

            bWritter.write(txtEditor.getText().toString()+"," +number+"\n");

            bWritter.close();

          ///*-*---------------------------------------------------------------*-*//


        FileWriter fileWritter = new FileWriter(LabelFile,true);
        BufferedWriter bufferWritter = new BufferedWriter(fileWritter);

        for (int i=0;i<10;i++) {
            bufferWritter.write(txtEditor.getText().toString()+"," +number+"\n");
        }

        MainActivity.traincount++;
        number=number+1;
        Writter.write("a," +number);
        Writter.close();
        bufferWritter.close();

        BufferedReader br = null;
        String line = "";
        String cvsSplitBy = ",";

        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(LabelFile));

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                // use comma as separator
                country = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
                text.setText(country[1]);
                //write=true;
            }
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (br != null) {
                try {
                    br.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } 

        Toast.makeText(this, "The contents are saved in the file.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        MainActivity.in=false;
        FdActivity.my=true;
        FdActivity.counterForClick=0;

        MainActivity.CounterForRecog=17;
        MainActivity.counterForUnknown=11;

        Intent objIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),   FdActivity.class);
        startActivity(objIntent);    
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
```

FdActivity.class(1st Activity)

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.face_detect_surface_view);

    new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {                 
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {  // this will send data through UI Thread, so you must update any UI Control only within this code.
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    counterForClick++;

                    if(counterForClick==6){
                        if(MainActivity.in==false) {
                            //my=true;
                            camera1.takePicture(null, null, mPicture1);
                            counterForClick=0;
                        }
                    }
               }
            });
        }
    }, 0, 500);  
}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please elaborate the problem faced with requisite snippets of code for others to take a look. For example, show where you define the variable that becomes `null`.

Answer (score 1):

This is how the system manages its memory. The activity lifecycle is [documented](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html), and allows for such interruptions. So, your activity should implement `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()`, just carefully follow the [instructions](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html).

Working with camera in such scenario is a challenge, and I usually prefer to stick to one camera-based activity, and manage the in-app navigation via fragments.

Comment: I have read the instructions, but I am still confused that In my case I have camera and I don't know how to restore the previous state of camera.

Comment: The instance of **FdActivity** is destroyed, and then recreated from scratch. From your code snippet, it is impossible to tell how the **camera1** member of this class is initialized, but somehow, when you return to this activity back from *activity3*, this initialization does not happen.